# Jquery validation not working on staging and production systems

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using jquery.validate.js in my MVC Cshtml project and for some reason the validations seem to work fine on my dev machine but fail to work on production machine

This is my jquery bundle

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"
                ));
```

This is my cshtml

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ChosenJq")
     <script type="text/javascript">
.....
```

All jquery scripts are in the right order i.e. Jquery included first and then . The code base on both the dev machine and the stag and prod machines are the same. The code works fine on the dev machine as seen below.(For email id)
[image]

But the validation just does not happen on either staging or production machines as seen below

[image]

On the console I see this error on all machines.

[image]

But it doesnt seem to affect me on the dev machine but only on the prod ones. 
Has anyone faced this before. I searched on SO but I couldnt relate to them

```
Staging and Production Environments: IIS, Windows Server 2008 R2
```

Comment: Where is the jquery-{version}.js file?

Comment: Its added before this.

Comment: Kind of exact issue with me as well, how did you solved ?

Comment: This remained unsolved, a year back now, so dont remember what eventually happened with it

Answer (score 2):

Actually during `Staging` the bundle did only ship the `min` files and hence include the `min` file versions in your bundle as follow.

```
 "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
```

**Or**

Set the EnableOptimization property as `false` to ship the non-min files during staging.

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

Comment: Well actually originally I had both.Still doesnt work.